# Android - Change audio pitch

Tags: android, soundpool

I have some audio files in my raw folder and I want to change their pitch using, for example, a seekbar.
I can do this with soundpool, but I can only play short sounds (up to 5 secs).
How can I change the pitch of long sounds?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/musicg/source/browse/src/com/musicg/main/test/resample.java?r=efc41eb4720952191ea18f8f520134d71cdf5e8f ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SoundPool soundPool;
int soundID;
soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundID = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.no, 1);
//play(int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)
float pitch=0.8f;
//{0.5f,0.6f,0.7f,0.8f,0.9f,1.0f,1.1f,1.2f,1.3f,1.4f,1.5f,1.6f,1.7f,1.8f,1.9f,2.0f}
soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, data.get(item));
```